# Resetting animation-duration when animation-play-state is paused? But not restarting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have an animation that can be paused and unpaused. However currently it is not very accurate... it's supposed to correspond to a timer ticking down.

code pen: http://codepen.io/meek/pen/zradga

It's accurate enough if you let it run, but once you start pausing/unpausing it starts behaving unexpectedly. I want to be able to skip to different parts in the animation to ensure the animation is always correct. How can I do this?

```
  function activateTimer() {
    if(inProgress===false) {

      // set animation timer and state

      if(currentTimer=='session') {
        $('#cover').css('animation-duration', sSession + 's');
      }
      else {
        $('#cover').css('animation-duration', sBreak + 's');
      }
      $('#cover').css('animation-play-state', 'running');

      inProgress = true;
      updateTimer(sSession);
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(sSession==session*60) {
          // because repeating this destroys the animation's linearity
          $('#cover').css('animation-duration', sSession + 's');
          sSession -= 1;
          updateTimer(sSession);
        }
        else if(sSession>1 && sSession<session*60) {
          currentTimer = 'session';
          // session time!
          focusSession();
          sSession -= 1;
          updateTimer(sSession);
        }
        else if(sSession==1) {
          sSession -= 1;
          updateTimer(sSession);
        }
        else {
          // break time!
          // if first frame of timer, restart animation
          if(sBreak==breaks*60) {
            focusBreak();
            currentTimer = 'break';
            sBreak -= 1;
            updateTimer(sBreak);
            restartAnimation();
            $('#cover').css('animation-duration', sBreak + 's');
            $('#cover').css('animation-play-state', 'running');
          }
          else if(sBreak>1 && sBreak<breaks*60) {  
            sBreak -= 1;
            updateTimer(sBreak);
          }
          else if (sBreak==1){
            // start a new session
            sBreak -= 1;
            updateTimer(sBreak);
          }
          else if (sBreak==0) {
            sSession = session*60;
            sBreak = breaks*60;
            updateTimer(sSession);
            focusSession();
            restartAnimation();
            $('#cover').css('animation-duration', sSession + 's');
          }
        }
      }, 1000);

    }
    else {
      inProgress = false;
      clearInterval(interval);

      // pause animation
      $('#cover').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');

    }
  }
```

Comment: when I am pausing and unpausing the the ticks deisappear is that the problem ?

Comment: @яша yes, the animation is supposed to resume, but either it just makes the ticks disappear or it gets mistimed.